# Magento - how do you see sales and discounts that use a catalog price rule

Tags: magento, report, reporting

I have a Magento site. I'd like to know how effective my sales have been. I ran a sale last month on a certain category of product. I used a catalog price rule for a 10% discount.

I would like to know the total dollar amount during a specific period of time sold and how much of a discount was given compared to the full price.

When I am looking at the reports in Magento I can see discounts based on coupon codes. I can see the total of the sales and the total of the discounts. I just can't find a similar report if the discount was given due to a catalog rule.

The developer of the site had installed an extra plugin for being able to see sales by sku, but can't for the life of me find where catalog price rule report would be.

Thanks for the help and advice!

Comment: You should ask this over on https://magento.stackexchange.com/. Stack Overflow is for questions about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?